# Shortcut Option Issue

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, gaming

When I add options to the end of a shortcut target, the quotes disappear. Every time.

**From** ["D:\Steam\steamapps\common\Unturned\Unturned.exe" -nographics -batchmode +secure]

**To** [D:\Steam\steamapps\common\Unturned\Unturned.exe -nographics -batchmode +secure]

This only occurs after I hit apply or ok. 
Help please?

Comment: Does it break your shortcut? It shouldn't, since there are no spaces in the path.

Comment: @BenN The way the shortcut is setup is designed to start a server, but once I remove the additional options it functions correctly

Comment: If the quoted path doesn't need quote (no psaces) they will automatically be removed -- this is normal and shouldn't affect anything, so your problem is probably in your aruments.  If you just run `D:\Steam\steamapps\common\Unturned\Unturned.exe -nographics -batchmode +secure` at a command prompt, does it work as expected?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Neither that nor attempting with quotations directly through cmd worked, Must be outdated instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the quoted path doesn't need quote (no psaces) they will automatically be removed when you save the shortcut.  This is normal and shouldn't affect anything.

If you just run `D:\Steam\steamapps\common\Unturned\Unturned.exe -nographics -batchmode +secure` at a command prompt and it fails, then there's something wrong with your command and/or the arguments you've provided.

Specific to Unturned, the [various](http://unturned.wikia.com/wiki/Hosting_a_Dedicated_Server) [tutorials](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=373696859) seem to say that the `+secure` command should be like `+secureserver/Your server`, so perhaps that's where your problem exists.